# SimpleSamlphp Error: State information lost, and no way to restart the request

Tags: php, authentication, single-sign-on, saml, simplesamlphp

I'm having troubles with a SSO implemented with SimpleSamlphp.

I have configured everything as follows:

authsources.php

```
'default-sp' => array(
    'saml:SP',
    'entityID' => '{{URLSP}}',
    'idp' => '{{URLIDP}}',
    'discoURL' => NULL,
    'privatekey' => 'saml.pem',
    'certificate' => 'saml.crt',
),
```

authsources.php (Idp)

```
'example-userpass' => array(
    'exampleauth:Static',
    'ecid' => '152',
    'orgdir' => '{{}}',
    'message' => '{{}}',

),
```

And I set the metadata correctly in saml20-idp-remote / saml20-sp-remote

The error I'm getting is:

```
State information lost, and no way to restart the request.

0: xxxlib/SimpleSAML/Auth/State.php:154 (SimpleSAML_Auth_State::loadState)
1: xxx/modules/saml/www/sp/saml2-acs.php:31 (require)
2: xxx/www/module.php:137 (N/A)
```

I've checked the SAML response and I've seen that the signature values are different, could be that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted, I had to specify the RelayState.